# pipeline and placeholder arguments

Tags: elixir

How is it possible to pass the pipeline placeholder to the second argument in a function?

```
defdefmodule CamelCase do
  str = "The_Stealth_Warrior"
  def to_camel_case(str) do 
    str 
    |> Regex(~r/_/, 'need_to_pass_str_argument_here', "") 
    |> String.split(" ")
    |> Enum.map(&(String.capitalize(&1)))
    |> List.to_string   
  end
end


ExUnit.start 

defmodule TestCamelCase do
  use ExUnit.Case
  import CamelCase, only: [to_camel_case: 1]

  test "to_camel_case" do
    assert to_camel_case("The_Stealth_Warrior") == "TheStealthWarrior"
  end
end

# Error 
iex> 
  ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Regex.replace/4
  (elixir) lib/regex.ex:504: Regex.replace("The_Stealth_Warrior", ~r/\W/, " ", [])
```

Comment: You can just use the built-in [`Macro.camelize/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Macro.html#camelize/1) if that's all you want to do

Comment: Hey @Sheharyar, I agree this was more for just practicing with Elixir pipelines.

Answer (score 5):

To pass the string as the second argument using pipes you can use anonymous function:

```
iex(1)> "The_Stealth_Warrior" |> (fn s -> Regex.replace(~r/_/, s, "") end).()
"TheStealthWarrior"
```

But, for this specific case, you can use `String.replace/3` instead which accepts a String as the first argument and Regex as the second argument:

```
iex(2)> "The_Stealth_Warrior" |> String.replace(~r/_/, "")
"TheStealthWarrior"
```

(`\W` doesn't match `_` so I changed it for demo purposes.)

Comment: Thanks at the end of the anonymous function  .()  is this just invoking this function?

Comment: With the trailing `.()` the anonymous function will be invoked with one argument: the value being passed through the pipe.